# How to access an object property inside a function that's inside a class

Tags: class, object

I was trying to fetch the ID that has been created from a new class to use it as a data key, but I can't seem to be able to access it. How can be able to do so, kindly help.

My code has a class and a function that uses the class to create a new item and append it onto a main container in my html file.

I want to use the setAttribute method to add a data-key and link the ID that has been created by the function createProjectItem() in the class but it says that the new class(newProject) has not been defined.

```js
class NewProject {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  createProjectItem() {
    const projectArray = {
      title: this.title,
      id: Date.now(),
      //ID TO BE ACCESSED ↑↑
    };
    projectArrayList.push(projectArray)
    console.log(projectArrayList);
  }
}


const createProjectList = document.querySelector(".create-projectList");

export default function createProjectFromClass() {
  createProjectList.addEventListener("click",() => {

    //Creates new class
    const Titleinput = document.getElementById("project-title");
    const titleText = Titleinput.value.trim();

    if (titleText !== "") {
      const newProject = new NewProject(titleText);
      newProject.createProjectItem()
      console.log(newProject.id);
      Titleinput.value = "";
    }

    //Append new class to projects list
    function appendProject() {
      const container = document.querySelector(".projects");
      const createProject = document.querySelector(".create-project")
      const projectList = document.createElement("div");
      projectList.setAttribute("class","project-list project-dynamic");
      projectList.setAttribute("data-key",newProject.id)
      //DATA KEY TO FETCH ID FROM NEW CLASS ↑↑

      projectList.innerHTML = `
        <p>Project name</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
      `
      container.insertBefore(projectList,createProject);
    }
    appendProject()

  })
}
```

I access the property

```js
let projectArrayList = [];

class NewProject {
  constructor(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  createProjectItem() {
    const projectArray = {
      title: this.title,
      id: Date.now(),
    };
    projectArrayList.push(projectArray)
    console.log(projectArrayList);
  }
}


export default function createProjectFromClass() {
  createProjectList.addEventListener("click",() => {
    // Create a new project from project class
    const Titleinput = document.getElementById("project-title");
    const titleText = Titleinput.value.trim();

    if (titleText !== "") {
      const newProject = new NewProject(titleText);
      newProject.createProjectItem()
      console.log(newProject.id);
      Titleinput.value = "";
    }

    //Append newProject to projects list
    function appendProject() {
      const container = document.querySelector(".projects");
      const createProject = document.querySelector(".create-project")
      const projectList = document.createElement("div");
      projectList.setAttribute("class","project-list project-dynamic");
      projectList.setAttribute("data-key","?????")
      projectList.innerHTML = `
        <p>Project name</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
      `
      container.insertBefore(projectList,createProject);
    }
    appendProject()

  })
}
```